# How does HandlerManager work with source?

Tags: gwt, event-bus

I've analyzed [HandlerManager](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java) and **I do not** see how it handles event source. Line 117:

```
public void fireEvent(GwtEvent<?> event) {
    ...
    Object oldSource = event.getSource();
    event.overrideSource(source);
    try {

      // May throw an UmbrellaException.
      eventBus.fireEvent(event); // <--- LOOK HERE
    } catch (com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException e) {
      throw new UmbrellaException(e.getCauses());
    } finally {
      ....
    }
}
```

But [simple event bus](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java) implementation has following code, line 86:

```
@Override
public void fireEvent(Event<?> event) {
    doFire(event, null); // <---- SOURCE IS NULL???
}

@Override
public void fireEventFromSource(Event<?> event, Object source) {
    if (source == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("Cannot fire from a null source");
    }
    doFire(event, source);
}
```

So, HandlerManager **does not** fire events with source, because it always calls *doFire(event, null);*

Could you make it clear how does HandlerManager fire event for source? As HandlerManager used in Widget, how does it fire events for Widget instance only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doFire` in `SimpleEventBus` only changes the event's source if the `source` argument is not `null`.

`HandlerManager` first sets the event's source with `overrideSource` and then call `doFire` with an implicit `null` source so it won't overwrite it.

QED.

Comment: But list of handlers populated like this, where source is still null: 

    List<H> handlers = getDispatchList(event.getAssociatedType(), source);

It does not retrieve handlers for event.source, does it?

Comment: No, but handlers in a `HandlerManager` are always registered without a `source`. To be clear: `HandlerManager` never uses the _with source_ feature of `EventBus`, it instead _forces_ the events' source using `overrideSource` in its `fireEvent`.

Comment: It looks like HandlerManager designed for using within Widget it created in. I can't see any benefits in forcing event source value.

Comment: Historically, `HandlerManager` was added in GWT 1.6 to back the _new_ event handling mechanism of widgets, and was (and still is) designed to be only used for this purpose. Then GWT 2.1 added the Places, Activities and RequestFactory APIs all using an `EventBus`. Originally, the event bus was simply a `HandlerManager`, but then it was decided to extract a _true_ `EventBus` and to rewrite `HandlerManager` on top of it (rather than duplicating code). Finally, `EventBus` gained _with source_ methods, which proved it was a good idea to have separate classes.